# How do streams and asyncEngine count work together in CUDA

Tags: cuda

CUDA defines a few parameters and I'm not really sure how CUDA behaves, if I have to respect them, or if I don't respect them it does run, but maybe not with the best performance.

When looking at `cudaGetDeviceProperties` I can see a few parameters (taken from the NVidia website: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0:

`concurrentKernels`: Device can possibly execute multiple kernels concurrently

> Is this just a flag or is there any impact? I think
> concurrent kernels only make sense if streams are used, right? (see also asyncEngineCount).

`asyncEngineCount`: Number of asynchronous engines

> Is this the number of kernels that can possibly run in parallel as
> given above. Also here I think this only works when streams are used,
> right?

This leads me to a **more general question about streams**. How many streams can be used or allocated at all? For example if the `asyncEngineCount` is 3, does it even make sense to have more than 3 streams? If this is not true what I say, does it make sense to allocate more streams than the `asyncEngineCount`.

What would happen if I allocate more streams than asyncEngineCount and let multiple kernels run concurrently? Lets assume I allocate 10 streams and run 10 kernels concurrently, but the asyncEngineCount only has 3. Would CUDA only run 3 kernels at a time and the other ones are blocked until a stream is free?

I always interpreted a stream as a simple synchronization object that gets non-signalled when a CUDA async method is invoked so that other methods are waiting  until the method exits and the stream is set to signalled, but that seems an oversimplified explanation from my side maybe?

I couldn't find a good explanation around async execution and streams, maybe with a deeper insight. The CUDA docs do not seem to explain details. Maybe there is a good explanation in the web or a book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just a flag or is there any impact?

It's a flag, a capability indicator.  I think basically all CUDA GPUs are capable of running concurrent kernels.  I'd be very surprised if anyone came across a CUDA GPU that doesn't have that capability.

> I think concurrent kernels only make sense if streams are used, right?

Yes, to arrange any sort of concurrency in CUDA (two or more things happening at the same time) its usually necessary to make proper use of streams.  There are a few minor exceptions to this, such as the concurrency of host code execution and device code execution.

> Is this the number of kernels that can possibly run in parallel as given above.

No it is not. An async engine in CUDA can be thought of as a DMA engine, and it is needed/used any time you issue an  asynchronous data transfer request (e.g. `cudaMemcpyAsync`) that has the actual capability to run asynchronously.  In order to make the transfer happen asynchronously, a hardware engine is used, and that engine is called an async engine.  Async engines have no usage or bearing with respect to kernel activity, except that using an async engine would allow, for example, a data transfer activity to happen at the same time as a kernel is executing, subject to various requirements and device capacity.

> This leads me to a more general question about streams. How many streams can be used or allocated at all? For example if the asyncEngineCount is 3, does it even make sense to have more than 3 streams?

There isn't a specified upper limit to the number of streams that can be created.  I have seen properly designed codes that use 40+ streams.  Streams have no direct connection to the `asyncEngineCount`.  If you create and use more streams than the amount of *device connections*, [the streams will distribute themselves](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-many-streams-maximum-number-of-streams/6571) ("alias") across device connections, but device connections also has nothing explicit to do with  async engines.

> What would happen if I allocate more streams than asyncEngineCount and let multiple kernels run concurrently? Lets assume I allocate 10 streams and run 10 kernels concurrently, but the asyncEngineCount only has 3. Would CUDA only run 3 kernels at a time and the other ones are blocked until a stream is free?

Nothing unusual would happen.  There is no connection between `asyncEngineCount` and streams, or the number of kernels you can execute concurrently.  Concurrent kernel execution depends on factors and resources that have no connection to `asyncEngineCount`, and you can certainly demonstrate more than `asyncEngineCount` kernels running concurrently, and the last time I checked, the [concurrentKernels](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/concurrentKernels) sample code does that.  There is an [upper bound/hardware limit](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) (see table 18) to the number of concurrent kernels, but it has no relation to async engines.

> I couldn't find a good explanation around async execution and streams,

For general CUDA learning, I usually recommend [this online training series](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) and the section on "CUDA Concurrency" has relevant information for this topic.  The [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) also has an extended section on Asynchronous Concurrent Execution in CUDA.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. You are answering - as always - all of my questions ;-)